# How does Text layout framework (TLF) insert breakElement?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tlf

I am using TLF 3.0 with Flex 3.6 SDK.
As you all know that every time a user hits 'Enter', it creates a new paragraph.
I read that TLF supports breakElement but I don't know how it's being inserted through the keyboard interaction.

Any ideas?
Thank you,

Handi

Comment: It never does: you'd have to override the default behaviour (before you ask: I do not readily know how to do that)

Comment: Yeah..that's what I thought too. It's just odd to me that Adobe would make breakElement available without keyboard-support to insert into TextFlow. Other editor uses 'Shift+Enter' to do the break. Oh well..I guess I have to mess around the framework.

Comment: After doing some experiments and looking at the TLF code, I found out that TLF doesn't render actual breakElement('<BR/>'). Any <BR/> will be replaced with <P> automatically. I am open to anyone who said otherwise.